Using btrfs to share home across systems
I have several arch-based distros on a laptop, all having their root filesystem on a shared lvm-on-luks setup (one lvm volume each).
I'd like having a common /home partition for them all, but some files can't really be shared: Documents, Downloads, .bash* are fine, but .cache, .local are not (they depend too much on the system).
What I'm doing now is a separate home partition which I mount in /home/data in all OSes.
Then I symlink the shared content, for example ln -s ../data/Documents Documents.
I was wondering if there's a better solution, like some kind of overlayfs or btrfs subvolume magic? Or anything else, really.
